# Regular pentagon vector proof

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given that $v = DC = \lambda EB$, prove that $\lambda v = CB + ED$.

## [image: diagram]

Whatever I try seems to end up with $CB + ED = (\frac {1}{\lambda} - 1)v$, ie:

$$CB + ED = CD + DE + EB + ED = EB - DC = EB - v$$ so $$ CB + ED = \frac {1}{\lambda}v - v = (\frac {1}{\lambda} - 1)v $$

Answer (score 4):

From $CB=\lambda DA$ and $ED=\lambda AC$ we get
$$CB+ED = \lambda (DA+AC) = \lambda DC = \lambda v.$$

---

In fact $\lambda=\varphi$ is the golden ration, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Derivation_of_the_diagonal_length_formula).

So we have
$$\lambda=\frac1\lambda-1.$$

So your result is not incorrect. In fact, if we combine your computation together with mine, we get the proof that
$$\lambda=\frac1\lambda-1.$$